# IDictionary error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean get_Item(System.String)' method,

Tags: entity-framework-4, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have this line of code in my WCF Entity Framework code

```
if (criteria.AccommodationTypes != null && criteria.AccommodationTypes.Count > 0)
   result = result.Where(a => criteria.AccommodationTypes[a.Type]);
```

That is causing this error when executed

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

AccommodationTypes is an IDictionary.  I can see that the problem is that EF cannot translate my code into SQL and that's why it's failing but I can't see what query I need to write to carry out this functionality.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has a similar issue in the future, here is how I solved it.  I created a list of all the values in the dictionary I was interested in (those for which the corresponding boolean was true) and then performed a contains in the query on that list.

```
var types = (from type in criteria.AccommodationTypes where type.Value select type.Key).ToList();

if (criteria.AccommodationTypes != null && criteria.AccommodationTypes.Count > 0)
  result = result.Where(a => types.Contains(a.Type));
```